# Why is there no uuid.uuid2 in Python?

Tags: python, uuid

[There's a `uuid.uuid1`, `uuid.uuid3`, `uuid.uuid4`, and `uuid.uuid5` but no `uuid.uuid2`.](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/uuid.html)

What happened to `uuid2`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [What's new in Python 2.5](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.5.html) in which `uuid` module was added for the first time:

> (Version 2 UUIDs are not specified in [RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122.html) and are not
> supported by this module.)

Answer (score 12):

The UUID2 is a special UUID generated in combination with [DCE Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_2_.28DCE_Security.29) server. It's rarely used nowadays. I guess the effort to implement that was in no relation to the request for such a functionality.